# react native setState in setInterval(), then setInterval executes error

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here is my code

```
componentDidMount() {
    let that = this;
    setInterval(() => {
        that.setState({number: 1});
    }, 2000);
}
```

I have writen `'let that = this;'`, but it's also error. In 2 seconds it executes more than once.

Comment: you initiate `that` but use `self` int the interval function

Comment: What's the error?? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad, i execute setInterval() many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why aren't you using `this` itself in the `setInterval`? You have used the [fat arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions) function, so you still can use `this` inside.

Here's a sample code:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        number: 0
    } 
  }

componentDidMount(){
  setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({number: parseInt(this.state.number, 10) + 1 });
  }, 2000);

}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',}}>
      <Text>
       {this.state.number }
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[Expo Demo](https://sketch.expo.io/ryGDuORix)